# Cytoscape Catalina

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, cytoscape

after updatiung to Catalina MacOs, Cytoscape is no longer working. Strangely I cannot find any indication on the web of people having the same problem. The script outputs:

```
Target Cytoscape version: 3.7.2
Your shell is bash
Fail: This version of OS is not supported: 10.15.2
Please upgrade your system to 10.11 or newer.
```

Comment: I don't know what you expect from this particular forum. Sounds to me like Cytoscape are just slow with updating their software.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here. One is the troubleshooting script. That needs to be updated for sure and we've opened a bug to do that. But more importantly, Cytoscape itself should work just fine. We have tested 3.7.2 on Catalina without issue. Our test was installing via the dmg. And then opening via the application icon. Can you try reinstalling and opening that way?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alexander Pico. I tried to reinstall and I installed Cytoscape on another computer, too. In both cases it does not start from the icon. Meanwhile I found out I can run it though the terminal using the .sh file.